# Finding Number of Times a number in array

Tags: java

I am almost at end of code. I am supposed to find number of times numbers appeared in a given array. The for loop is not working as expected.

They contain numbers in an array, I am able to extract individual numbers which are repeating. Then I am trying to find how many time that an individual number is appeared by using for loop and store it into another array which will give me the count.

Everything is declared like `d[]`, `b[]`, `c[]`

```
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        if (d[i] == c[j]) {
            b[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output should be, like if if's condition to be true, `b[i]` should increment the number of times a number appeared but it is giving me array of ones, like it is only passing through the if condition once per `i`.

Comment: Update the question with declarations of arrays and `l` and `k` variables

Comment: <what m.antkowicz said> + Could you update the question with inputs?

Comment: Formatted code and fixed grammar

Comment: Do you have any limits on how big the number in your initial array can be?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using for example a Hashtable saving the array numbers as keys and the number of repetitions as value. This function receive an array of Integers, and returns the Hashtable with the repetitions:

```
public static Hashtable<Integer, Integer> getRepitedNumbers( Integer[] numbers) {

    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> Result = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

    for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

        if( Result.containsKey( numbers[ i])) {
            //If the current number is saved in the hashtable, you need to increment the
            //value (repetitions counter for this number)
            Result.put( numbers[ i], Result.get( numbers[ i]) + 1);
        } else {
            //If the current number doesn't exist, is the first occurrence.
            Result.put( numbers[ i], 1);
        }
    }
    //At the end you have a hashtable with each number and the number of occurrences
    return Result;

}
```

Comment: but can,t i just make an array counting number of repetition . it seems that in my code once if statement turned true once it is not checking for other same numbers in the array .

Comment: Why are you recommending to use obsolete collection Hashtable? HashMap should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listOfIntegers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9);
        Map<Integer, Long> integerToCount = listOfIntegers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it, Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(integerToCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `Streams`:

```
public static Map<Integer, Long> countItems(Integer[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```